# How to disable/workaround autoscrolling to the end of page on popup/div adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've written this code for popup creation:

```
function showPopup(titleString, contentHtml, widthInt, heightInt) {
var popupID = 'dialog-modal';
if ($("#"  + popupID).length == 0) {
    jQuery(document.body).append('<div id="' + popupID + '"/>');
}
var popup = $("#"  + popupID);

popup.html('<div id="' + popupID + '" style="width:100%; height:100%;">' + contentHtml + '</div>');
popup.dialog({
    width : widthInt,
    height : heightInt,
    title : titleString,
    modal : true
});
```

}

And this code is called on button click...

The matter is - when I click the button, at first time, page is scrolled to the end, and popup is shown there. It doesn't happen, on the second, etc times. (I mean, in 2,3... times, popup is shown in the middle of the current page position)

And seems, this is specific for chrome, because it doesn't happen in FF, or IE.

So, quetions are - why does it happen? and how to get rid of it?

(I'm writing on JS/html only the third day :) may be I've missed smth)

Call to method is done by button, generated from JSF :

```
<input type="button" name="form:j_idt85" value="Show list" class="show-list" onclick="showListInPopup()">
```

Comment: Am I reading correctly that you're adding a div with an id of popupID *within* a div with an id of popupID? That seems a bit strange. Remember: There can every only be one instance of a given ID on a page.  As for the jumping: Do you, by any chance, have an anchor in the href of your clicked button? (assuming you're using a link <a>). I think you're going to add a bit more code so we can help you. (And a Fiddle, maybe ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same behavior when the jquery ui stylesheet isn't included. Do you have the ui stylesheet on your page?

If not, try adding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```